# How to make a proxy server for python requests

Tags: python, server, python-requests, proxy

I have seen code like this that shows how to use a proxy for python requests.

```py
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://localhost:7777',
  'https': 'http://localhost:7777',
}

requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
requests.get('https://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

But I am wondering how can we make a very simple proxy server in Python that would be able to respond to the `GET` request?

Comment: I'm not sure but probably you could create proxy server even using web framework `Flask` to get request from browser, and `requests` to send it to expected server. But if you need real local proxy to test connection then you can use Python module/program [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) (`Man-In-The-Middle-Proxy`) or (not-python, not-free but work 30 days for free, and with GUI)  [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)

Comment: with google I found example which use `socket` - [server.py](https://github.com/anapeksha/python-proxy-server/blob/main/src/server.py)

Answer (score 3):

You can find many examples how to do it - even in questions on Stackoverflow.

Some of them use standard module `socket` (but it doesn't look simply).

Other use standard module `http` but they show code for `Python 2` which was using different names.

Version for Python 3

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import urllib.request

class MyProxy(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.path)
        url = self.path
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.copyfile(urllib.request.urlopen(url), self.wfile)

# --- main ---

PORT = 7777

httpd = None

try:
    socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True   # solution for `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`
    httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(('', PORT), MyProxy)
    print(f"Proxy at: http://localhost:{PORT}")
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Pressed Ctrl+C")
finally:
    if httpd:
        httpd.shutdown()
        #httpd.socket.close()
```

Test using page [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org)

```
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://localhost:7777',
  'https': 'http://localhost:7777',
}

response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', proxies=proxies)
print(response.text)

response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get?arg1=hello&arg2=world', proxies=proxies)
print(response.text)
```

But it works only for `HTTP`.

For `HTTPS` it may need to use `ssl.socket` from module `ssl`.

And it works only with `GET`.

For `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc. it would need `do_POST`, `do_PUT`, `do_DELETE`, etc. with different code.

---

**EDIT:**

```
    def do_POST(self):
        url = self.path

        # - post data -
        content_length = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length', 0)) # <--- size of data
        if content_length:
            content = self.rfile.read(content_length)               # <--- data itself
        else:
            content = None

        req = urllib.request.Request(url, method="POST", data=content)
        output = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        
        # ---
        
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.copyfile(output, self.wfile)
```

---

But if you need local proxy only to test your code then you could use

- Python module/program: [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) (`Man-In-The-Middle-Proxy`)
- not-python, not-free (but work 30 days for free), with nice GUI: [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)

More complex [OWASP ZAP](https://www.zaproxy.org/getting-started/), [Burp Suite (community edition)](https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload)